# Using the ui-select tagging with angular formly passing a function to attribute tagging

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I have created a custom template to angular-formly using ui-select to tagging input:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'ui-tagging',
        extends: 'select',
        template: '<ui-select multiple tagging="" tagging-label="(\'new\')" ng-model="model[options.key]" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="{{to.required}}" ng-disabled="{{to.disabled}}"> <ui-select-match placeholder="{{to.placeholder}}"> {{$select.selected[to.labelProp || \'name\']}} </ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices repeat="option in to.options | filter: $select.search"> <div ng-bind-html="option | highlight: $select.search"></div> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>',
    });
```

Here is the problem, i want set a function to attribute tagging to transform the tags, like example in the ui-select docs.

```
<ui-select tagging="tagTransform" .....
```

Plunker with ui-select example: http://plnkr.co/edit/m1SQXUxftBLQtitng1f0?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you'd simply reference a function on your field options. Something like: `options.templateOptions.tagTransform` (which has a shortcut: `to.tagTransform`). So you could have something like:

```
formlyConfig.setType({
        name: 'ui-tagging',
        extends: 'select',
        template: '<ui-select multiple tagging="to.tagTransform()" tagging-label="(\'new\')" ng-model="model[options.key]" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="{{to.required}}" ng-disabled="{{to.disabled}}"> <ui-select-match placeholder="{{to.placeholder}}"> {{$select.selected[to.labelProp || \'name\']}} </ui-select-match> <ui-select-choices repeat="option in to.options | filter: $select.search"> <div ng-bind-html="option | highlight: $select.search"></div> </ui-select-choices> </ui-select>',
    });
```

And the field config would be something like:

```
{
  type: 'ui-tagging',
  templateOptions: {
    tagTransform: function() {}
  }
}
```